# QuarkusTest giving `could not resolve the bean of type` during injection

Tags: testing, junit5, quarkus

Solved this issue already just documenting here incase someone else runs across it.

But I noticed when I tried to `@InjectMock` or `@InjectSpy` inside of one of my `@QuarkusTest` I kept getting an error that included:
`could not resolve the bean of type`

And the bean I was trying to mock looked like:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyAppBean {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Inject
    GroupMapper groupMapper;

    @Inject
    Logger logger;


    public void method() {
        logger.info("Do something")

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, Mockito injection does not like when you define global variables the issue above had to do with the fact that I defined the "ObjectMapper" I was able to fix it pretty easily by changing the class to look like this:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyAppBean {

    ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Inject
    GroupMapper groupMapper;

    @Inject
    Logger logger;

    void onStart(@Observes StartupEvent ev) {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }


    public void method() {
        logger.info("Do something")

    }

}
```